# Windows 7 "Devices and Printers" like interface

Tags: wpf, windows-7, wpf-controls

I want to make a window interface just like "Devices and Printers" window in Windows 7 in which items can be suppressed and drilled down. Any ideas how can i build such a view and which controls from wpf can be used.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that there is an "Expander" control which provides similar functionality that i am looking for. You can also see it here http://www.wpftutorial.net/Expander.html